# R: creating a 3D matrix based on a colum value

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix that has the following first two columns: location, year.  This is followed by 50 columns, one for each calendar day.  The columns for days have either an 'NA' if the location was not visited, or a 1 if the location was.

example:

```
Location Year 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 8  9  10 .... 50
Site1    2005 NA NA NA 1  NA NA 1 NA NA 1  .... NA
Site2    2006 NA NA 1  NA NA NA 1 NA NA 1  .... NA
```

I have used the reshape package before to create 4 dimensional matrices, with each column in the data frame used as a variable to melt and then cast the array.  But here, I have multiple columns and it does not seem to work as well.

I would like to create the following:

```
dim Y: locations
dim X: days 1-50
dim Z: Years
```

It's almost like extracting the data from each year, and stacking each location by day array one behind the other.  Does anybody know what the best way to create a three dimensional array this way might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what do you want to have (your give some values of the final result not just the structure, and some data to work on)

First I reproduce your data

```
dat <- data.frame(Location =c('Site1','Site2'),
           Year=c(2005,2006))
dat <- cbind(dat,matrix(sample(c(1,NA),100,rep=T),ncol=50))
```

Then using `reshape2` I get this :

```
library(reshape2)
melt(dat,id.vars=c('Location','Year'))
    Location Year variable value
1      Site1 2005        1    NA
2      Site2 2006        1    NA
3      Site1 2005        2     1
4      Site2 2006        2    NA
5      Site1 2005        3    NA
6      Site2 2006        3     1
7      Site1 2005        4     1
8      Site2 2006        4    NA
```

Comment: See my reply above, but I ended up creating a similar matrix, and then using the cast function in reshape to create the three dimensions that I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there might be a cleaner way to do with the `reshape2` library, but using lapply will give you clean lists.  If you need them as an array, just convert as

```
arr <- lapply(unique(dat$Location), function(L) dat[dat$Location==L, -1])

# add names, to keep it neat
names(arr) <- unique(dat$Location)

# Convert to array if needed
arr <- as.array(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, but I just tried this and it just gives me a list by route.  I need an actual three dimensional matrix, where the rows are the location, the columns are the days, and the third dimension is the year.  Do you know what I might try in reshape2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to remove the NAs.

```
library(reshape2)

test <- read.table(text="Location Year 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 8  9  10
Site1    2005 NA NA NA 1  NA NA 1 NA NA 1
Site2    2006 NA NA 1  NA NA NA 1 NA NA 1", h=T)

melt(test, id = c("Location", "Year"), na.rm = TRUE, variable.name = "day")[, -4]

#    Location Year  day
# 6     Site2 2006   X3
# 7     Site1 2005   X4
# 13    Site1 2005   X7
# 14    Site2 2006   X7
# 19    Site1 2005  X10
# 20    Site2 2006  X10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This is what I ended up doing:         trial1 <- melt(data, id = c("Location", "Year"), na.rm = TRUE, variable.name="day")                                                                  
colnames(trial1) <- c("Location","Year","jday","Det")

det.matrix=cast(trial1, Location ~ jday ~ Year,measure.var="Det")
dim(det.matrix)